# ld: skipping incompatible /projets/unidmi/liv/x86/lib/liblogversion.so when searching for -llogversion

Tags: linux, makefile

I am getting the following compilation error in the Linux environment:

> /ld: skipping incompatible /projets/unidmi/liv/x86/lib/liblogversion.so

To solve the above error I have added the following linker options in the makefile:

`-c -L/usr/lib64`.

But after including the above linker option in makefile, we get the following error:
linker input file unused since linking not done.

If I remove the `-c` option, I get the following error:

> /usr/lib64/librt.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized

If I include the `-c` option, I get back the original error i.e.

> linker input file unused since linking not done.

Please let me know how to solve the above error!

Comment: Please let me know your suggestions on the above issue!

Comment: Please anyone, let me know your suggestions!